# WFS insert: GeoServer complains of foreign key constraint violation on unrelated key

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs, wfs-t

When inserting a feature in GeoServer using the WFS-T protocol I am getting back a database error response to the effect that the `INSERT` statement on the relevant table failed due to a foreign key violation. The table name is correct but the weird part is that the identifier complained about does not exist at all in the payload of the WFS request. No matter what value for the feature Id I use on the payload, the error message is about the same fixed key value (`108` in the error response below) that doesn't appear in the payload at all. This has been going on for a couple of days now.

I supply the WFS sent to GeoServer and the response. You will see that the WFS uses a dummy feature id (`fid="feature-id-666"`) and also `stable_id=555` (`stable_id` is a property of the Feature in my case) and the error is about `stable_id 108`.

I get the WFS payload and the error response from the Network tab on my browser's developer console.

WFS payload is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
  <Insert>
    <eae_stable_mapping xmlns="coredb" fid="feature-id-666">
      <geometry>
        <MultiPolygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:3857">
          <polygonMember>
            <Polygon srsName="EPSG:3857">
              <exterior>
                <LinearRing srsName="EPSG:3857">
                  <posList srsDimension="2">2441824.1162386383 4829505.778704044 2444124.9240303603 4828797.839673139 2442886.0247849966 4831806.586495766 2441824.1162386383 4829505.778704044</posList>
                </LinearRing>
              </exterior>
            </Polygon>
          </polygonMember>
        </MultiPolygon>
      </geometry>
      <stable_id>555</stable_id>
    </eae_stable_mapping>
  </Insert>
</Transaction>
```

Error response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://geoserver.iacs.lab.synelixis.com/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
    <ows:ExceptionText>java.io.IOException: Error occured on commit
Error occured on commit
ERROR: insert or update on table "eae_stable_mapping" violates foreign key constraint "eae_stable_mapping_stable_id_68179c73_fk_eae_lives"
  Detail: Key (stable_id)=(108) is not present in table "eae_livestock_stable".</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

How is it possible that a key `108` appears out of the blue when the payload only uses the dummy keys `feature-id-666` (for the feature id) and `stable_id=555` (for the property)? How should I go about investigating this further? Any ideas?

### update

We are investigating [https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/primarykey.html][1]and we think this may have something to do with the issue...

### update II

Upon further investigation this is related to the fact that the `stable_id` column we have in the database is unique. So what the GeoServer does in the case of this `unique` column is it totally disregards any value we supply int the WFS payload and simply inserts as value the next available number (it's doing a `max` on the column and then adds one). I think this is too magical. Prompted by this I asked a more general question: [https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/386039/158056][1]

### update III and solution

I believe we've gotten to the bottom of this. It is apparently a limitation in the OpenLayers library in that the `idgen` attribute cannot be set. More here: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/66008056/274677] [1]

Comment: turn the GeoServer logging level up to GEOTOOLS-DEV and you will see the actual SQL in the log file this should help you see what is going wrong in the DB

Comment: please discuss this on the GeoServer users list were we may be able to help with your specific use case

Answer (score 2):

I would first investigate this on the database basis. Try and insert the feature there and see what happens.

Also I would guess that the `stable_id` you provide could be ignored by the WFS and instead for example a sequence is managing that id field.

The actual error message is about a foreign key constraint preventing the insert. You have to first insert a `eae_livestock_stable` object before you can insert a `eae_stable_mapping` object for that stable.